# Retrieve Data from a Data Extension and Update Sales cloud record

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, sales-cloud

Is it possible to Retrieve Data from a Data Extension and Update Sales cloud record without using Data Sync or Sync Data extension.

If yes, what would be the approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` to update data on Sales/Service Cloud. This is an example from the doc:

```
%%[
var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead','00Q00003yAEj','Email','jcc@example.com')
]%%
```

> The system updates the Email field on the Lead with ID 00Q00003yAEj to
>   contain jcc@example.com.

To retreive data, you need to use the `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` function. It returns a rowset that you can loop through..

> Returns a rowset with the selected information from Salesforce objects
>   that match the criteria you specify. This function works only with an
>   account integrated with a Salesforce account. Include multiple sets of
>   ordinals 3, 4, and 5 to retrieve information as necessary. Because
>   this function returns data as a rowset, use Row() and Field() to
>   evaluate the data.

Example: The system returns the first name and last name of all leads in your Salesforce account where the region equals west:

```
%%[ var @rs
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'region', '=', 'west','AnnualRevenue', '>', '1000000')
]%%
```

**Reference:**

[UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm)

[RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)

Comment: Should we loop the functionality for multiple retrieving multiple records?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the Retreive function. And yes, it returns a rowset that you can loop through..